# Displaying Elements in UITableView like iPhone contacts, separated into alphabetical sections?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, sorting

I've been looking around on-line for a solution to this, but I can't seem to find anything, and I'm stuck.

I have a NSMutableArray:

```
productsToDisplay
```

Which consists of a heap of Product objects that each have a 'name' attribute e.g.

```
Product *product = ....

NSLog(@"%@", product.name);
```

Each cell displays a products name and when clicked, displays more information about the product.

However I have a lot of products and would like to split them up into alphabetical sections in the UITableView (like the Contacts on your iPhone are).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot,

Jack

[EDIT]
I realise I could just sort the array on the name attribute, but I would also like the quick search bar that runs down the right hand side of the UITableView so a user can easily find the section they are looking for.

Comment: Use CusstomTableviewcell

Comment: I just want to display the name in cell, so I'm fine in that department, I want to sort the cells themselves into alphabetical sections, like in the iPhones Contacts application.

Comment: Can't you just sort your array which contains Product details by name and than reload table to display sorted elements ?

Comment: Sorry @Jennis I missed out part of the problem. Yeh I tried that, but as I stated in the edit, I would like the quick search bar down the side of the UITableView as well so the user can quickly find the section they need.  As far as I'm aware that quick search bar only works with sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add alphabetic sections to ur tableview, then You have to create array of alphabets corresponding to the section in tableview. Like section[0] - 'A', section[1] - 'B', etc.

Add 
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return keys;
}
//the delegate is asking for an array of the values to display in the index.

So the first item in this array will take the user to the first section, which is section 0.

Answer (score 4):

use this delegate to display the right hand sections list:-

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return searchArray; 
}
```

use this delegate to associate table content (section) according to right hand list:-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    if (index == 0) {
    [tableView scrollRectToVisible:[[tableView tableHeaderView] bounds] animated:NO];
        return -1;
    }
    return index;
}
```